# JavaScript change height with trinary operator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to Change width and height on click, if the width is already 100% I want to Change it to 1400px, but somehow following does not work:

```
document.getElementById('btnFullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var imageView = document.getElementById('imageView');
    var canvasBody = document.getElementById('canvas-body');


    var items_arr = [canvasBody, videoPreview, wrapper, container, leftImageBox, imageView];

    for (i = 0; i < items_arr.length; ++i) {
        items_arr[i].style.width = items_arr[i].style.width != "100%;" ? "100%;" : "1400px;";
        items_arr[i].style.height = items_arr[i].style.height != "100%;" ? "100%;" : "1400px;";
        items_arr[i].style.minWidth = items_arr[i].style.minWidth != "100%;" ? "100%;" : "1400px;";
        items_arr[i].style.minHeight = items_arr[i].style.minHeight != "100%;" ? "100%;" : "1400px;";
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon: `"100%;"` to `"100%"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `;` with in dom value like `100%;`.And from this code `videoPreview` and `leftImageBox` both are undefined

```
document.getElementById('btnFullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var imageView = document.getElementById('imageView');
  var canvasBody = document.getElementById('canvas-body');
  var items_arr = [canvasBody, videoPreview, wrapper, container, leftImageBox, imageView];

  for (i = 0; i < items_arr.length; ++i) {
    items_arr[i].style.width = items_arr[i].style.width != "100%;" ? "100%" : "1400px";
    items_arr[i].style.height = items_arr[i].style.height != "100%;" ? "100%" : "1400px";
    items_arr[i].style.minWidth = items_arr[i].style.minWidth != "100%;" ? "100%" : "1400px";
    items_arr[i].style.minHeight = items_arr[i].style.minHeight != "100%" ? "100%" : "1400px";
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, how would you create a helper function for that with Parameters I tried following but I dont know how to proceed https://kopy.io/IpsKH

Comment: @Olipol https://kopy.io/VJysf see this .change the `==` to `=` with empty click assign .And also check the  elistener with `!eListener.trim()` .its better with `==""` .And dont forget to remove the `;` in string

Comment: How would I Need to call the function? It did not work like this? `setFullscreen('btnFullscreen', [
        document.getElementById('wrapper'),
        document.getElementById('container'),
        document.getElementById('imageView'),
        document.getElementById('canvas-body')
    ]
);`